# ASP.NET MVC Переход между контроллерами. Ссылки между контроллерами

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Искал ответы в гугле, не нашел, подскажите пожалуйста знающие люди.

Делаю Web приложение на ASP.NET с использованием MVC на FrameWork 4.8

Создал в студии пустой шаблон. В котором есть один контроллер Home, реализующий три View: Index (главная страница), About, Register (регистрация пользователя, запись в БД).

Я хочу вывести, все что связано с пользователем, в частности Register в отдельный контроллер.
Когда вывел, пришлось и View - Register вывести из папки Main контроллера в папку View контроллера Register. Все работает.

Но как сделать ссылку с MainController - View - Index.cshtml на RegisterController - View - Register?

Если я пишу код в index.cshtml, например:    @Html.ActionLink("Зарегистрироваться", "Register")
То сайт выдает мне URL: localhost:4444/Main/Register это соответственно ошибка 404
А нужно: localhost:4444/Reg/Register

Comment: [Генерация ссылок](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/9.5.php)

Comment: Если используете asp .net identity то а) это можно настроить (и вообще в стандартной поставке есть примеры - посмотрите на разметку в layouts) и б) это шибко зависит от номера используемой версии identity, в последних версиях перед core вендор вынес этот код в отдельную area. Если самопал - то используйте конструкцию вида `@Html.RouteLink("Sam", new { controller = "Home", action = "GetUser", name = "Sam", id = 12 }, new { id = "sam", @class = "link" })`